# Change color of individual edges or arrows of a TikZ path

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

How to individually change the color of the edges?
I tried with `to` but it ignores the color change. Also I'd like arrows to appear, say, how to correct the next lines so I get a four-colored square? (The 'vector addition' spirit should be kept. That is, I'd like to generate a long path inside a  single `draw` or `path`, so only one `;` should appear.)

I also tried with `edge' -- unsuccessfully too.

```
\documentclass[ border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}%


\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) to[-latex,blue] ++(0,1)
                  to[-latex,red] ++(1,0)
                  to[-latex,yellow] ++(0,-1)
                  to[-latex,green] ++(-1,0) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
\path (0,0) to[-latex,gray] ++(0,1)
                  to[-latex,gray] ++(1,0)
                  to[-latex,gray] ++(0,-1)
                  to[-latex,gray] ++(-1,0) -- cycle;
                  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In TikZ, color and arrow are global for a path. You need to have different paths to have different colors or arrow (or line styles, like dash). You can cheat using `edge` to avoid semicolon, but that will create different paths. See https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.1

Comment: About using edge, look for example the faq section in `circuitikz` manual: http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf

Comment: Thanks. It's somehow disappointing that I have to create nodes.

Comment: No need to create nodes; you can use named coordinates or edges...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ti*k*Z, color and arrow are global for a path. You need to have different paths to have different colors or arrows (or line styles, like dash). You can cheat using `edge` to avoid semicolons, but that will create different paths. See https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.1.

When using edges, you should remember that that operation *does not* affect the main path, but creates another one; specifically, it doesn't move the current point; in your case you want to move it, so you have to use twice the movement (one to specify the `edge` endpoint, the other one to move the path there):

```latex
\documentclass[ border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{cedge/.style={draw=#1,
    -latex}
}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) edge[cedge=blue] ++(0,1) ++(0,1)
        edge[cedge=red] ++(1,0) ++(1,0)
        edge[cedge=yellow] ++(0,-1) ++(0,-1)
        edge[cedge=green] ++(-1,0) ++(-1,0) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
        \path (0,0) edge[cedge=gray] ++(0,1) ++(0,1)
            edge[cedge=gray] ++(1,0) ++(1,0)
            edge[cedge=gray] ++(0,-1) ++(0,-1)
            edge[cedge=gray] ++(-1,0) ++(-1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change the first `\path` with a draw and draw the "base" path, you can see what the command is really doing by looking at the corners:

```
\draw (0,0) edge[cedge=blue] ++(0,1) -- ++(0,1)
        edge[cedge=red] ++(1,0) -- ++(1,0)
        edge[cedge=yellow] ++(0,-1) -- ++(0,-1)
        edge[cedge=green] ++(-1,0) -- ++(-1,0) -- cycle;
```

[image]

Comment: great, thanks for the last helpful insight!